# installiing prevoius .net frameworks before installing new one?

Tags: .net

Do i need to install .net frame work 1.1 and 2.0 before i install later versions (3.0)??
or the installation of the 3.0 framework alone is enough and provides support for softwares that were written on an earlier framework versions ?
thanks ,
liran

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't have to install previous frameworks.

I doubt there's many apps that require 1.1. However, if you have one of those, you might want to install 1.1, as there are some known breaking changes between 2.0 and 1.1, even though supposedly it should work fine.

3.0 build on top of 2.0, and includes 2.0 binaries and toolset in its installer. Anything that target 2.0 will work just fine on 3.0. (Actually, this is true even for 3.5).

4.0 has a brand new binaries and toolset; however it is designed to work side-by-side with 2.0/3.5. You can install 4.0 now and then install 2.0/3.5 later if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

.net assemblies, and .net itself, are meant to be able to run different versions separately, side by side.  I currently have 2.0, 3.5, and 4.0 running on this computer together..none requires the other or interferes with the other.

Short version: you'll be fine.   Though if you have an app that requires a specific version of the framework, you may want to install it.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't have to.

All framework versions install whatever is necessary for them to run on your computer.
None of the versions interfere with each other.

- 2.0 doesn't require 1.0 nor 1.1
- 3.0 and 3.5 require (and install) 2.0, because they are built on top of it
- 4.0 doesn't require any of the others, it has a new CLR as well